# How to change RPM metadata (version)?

Tags: rpm

I have a packaged RPM and I would like to repackage it so that is has the same contents but with a different version in metadata.

My use case is in a test where I need to simulate the presence of multiple versions of the same RPM, but I don't have the RPM sources or spec file available.

Searching on the Internet yielded nothing useful, most answers reference rpm2cpio but as I understand it, this is useful only when dealing with the contents, not the metadata.

How can I repackage a RPM with a different RPM version?

Answer (score 2):

[FPM](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) is probably the easiest way to do this. You can specify rpm as both the input and output formats, and then give it a version flag to override the source information.

Comment: https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/rpm.html:


Rename a package and assign different version:

fpm -t rpm -s rpm --name myruby --version $(date +%S) ruby-2.0.0.x86_64.rpm